# Python3 and Tkinter - How can I keep my widgets inside the Frame when they change size?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, resize

from a Tkinter point of view, I wrote a quite complex software. all widgets have been placed using the "place" geometry manager and by default my GUI interface is in English. unfortunately I realized that if I change the language, also the widgets size change, and when it happens, it creates a big mess. some of them come off the frames and other ones overlap others.

to solve this issue, I thought to change the geometry manager from "place" to "grid". I made some tests, but I can't reach my goal. see the example below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("550x350")

MyFrame=Frame(root, background="#ffffff", width=535, height=300, highlightbackground="#848a98", highlightthickness=1)
MyFrame.place(x=5, y=5)

def ChangeinItalian():
    MyLabel.configure(text="Ciao Ciao Ciao Ciao Ciao Ciao")
def ChangeinEnglish():
    MyLabel.configure(text="Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=16)
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, minsize=6)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=16)
root.grid_rowconfigure(2, minsize=16)
root.grid_rowconfigure(4, minsize=16)

MyLabel = ttk.Label(MyFrame, text="Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi Hi", background="#ffffff", style="BluText.TLabel")
MyLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)
Canvas(MyFrame, width=380, height=1, background="#a0a0a0", highlightthickness=9, highlightbackground="grey").grid(row=1, column=3)

MyButton=ttk.Button(MyFrame, text="Italian", width=16, command=ChangeinItalian)
MyButton.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="w")
MyButton=ttk.Button(MyFrame, text="English", width=16, command=ChangeinEnglish)
MyButton.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky="w")

root.mainloop()
```

when you change the language from English to Italian, the Canvas overcomes the farme, and it's a problem. is there a way to create an automatic resize process when my labels change their sizes because of the language?

[image]

Comment: `MyFrame` is None because it is the result of `Frame(...).place(...)`.  So you are not putting those label, canvas and buttons in `MyFrame`, but `root`.

Comment: ciao acw1668. you are right, I just fixed my code but I have an issue. MyFrame must always has a specific size (535x300) and not changing when MyLabe changes (I attached an image). is it possible reach my goal?

Comment: First move `width=535, height=300` from `MyFrame=Frame(...)` to `MyFrame.place(...)`.  Second add `MyFrame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)`.  Then `Canvas(...).grid(..., sticky='ew')`.